# Arrangement is required in XML?

Tags: xml, servlets, web.xml

I am confused with arrangement in the declaration Elements. Is there any difference if I write like this:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/web-application-context.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or like this?

```
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/web-application-context.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>

  <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: In general, XML tags (unlike attributes) are ordered. Schemas can require a specific order and XML-processing code can take the order into account when determining the meaning. But some choose not to, so I won't post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no:

- **yes** - the order of some elements like `<filter-mapping/>` is relevant, as it will change the order of actual filters being applied. Also the schema for `web.xml` defines the order of various elements.
- **no** - the order of other elements is irrelevant, e.g. the order in which you declare `<servlet/>`s. Also in your example it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thank you for you very kind reply. Woha! Its not that simple as I thought.. Can you please explain a bit more about web.xml?

Comment: @AbdulAziz: of course, but please be more specific. In a filter example: if you have two filters A and B mapped to the same URI, the order in which mappings appear in `web.xml` determines which filter runs first and which afterwards. But the `<filter/>` declarations alone are irrelevant.

Comment: Does pargm value should be like this  /WEB-INF/web-application-context.xml or like this  \WEB-INF\web-application-context.xml

Comment: @AbdulAziz definitely slashes (`/`)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Tomasz Nurkiewicz for your kind help. And sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @AbdulAziz: no problem, this is what this site is for :-).

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any difference, you can write in any order, provided you always open and close with proper tags.